# Processing: Draw function is duplicating the image instead of moving it to the mouse position

Tags: javascript, processing

I am making a game and I have a png character that is placed on the mouseX and mouseY. In theory, it should move to my mouse cursor but instead it creates a new image copy instead.

Here is my image and draw function related code:

`var img;`

```
var Setup = function() {
     img = loadImage("characterLarge.png");
};
```

```
draw = function() {
    if (isPlaying === true) {
        imageMode(CENTER);
        image(img, mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
        };
};
```

I tried changing image modes which only displaced the image, I tried using a string but the string was identified as incorrect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With a little modification, your code runs without error in the p5.js Web Editor, sketch.js file.  Your difficulty might be due to syntax:

```
var img;
var isPlaying = true;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  img = loadImage("xxxx.png");
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  if (isPlaying === true) {
    imageMode(CENTER);
    image(img, mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
  }
}
```

**To run in html:**
reference: https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js

*Note that syntax is the same as 'regular' Processing source code that will run in the Processing editor, Java mode.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.0/processing.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="application/processing">
      PImage img;
      boolean isPlaying = true;
      
      void setup(){
        size(400, 400);
        img = loadImage("xxxx.png");
      }

      void draw(){
        background(209);
        if(isPlaying == true){
          imageMode(CENTER);
          image(img, mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
        }      
       }
    </script>
    <canvas> </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i changed the functions into the ``` function setup() {``` format in your comment and it still does not work. I forgot to mention that the isPlaying is already in there, I just forgot to include it. All the other functions work as intended when I convert them, only draw is not working,

Comment: The posted code runs perfectly on my system so there must be some other problem. I ran the code in p5.js Web Editor with a Chrome browser.  In addition, I tested it in the Processing editor in p5.js mode with a Safari browser and it worked as expected there also.  The .png image is locked to the cursor and follows it around the window.

Comment: Do to the nature of the assignment I must keep all my code in a single HTML file. Essentially, i have ``` <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.4.8/processing.js"></script> ````and then in the script tag i have to have all my code.

Comment: Any way to post the entire html file?  You could edit your original post or add an addendum.

Comment: My teacher does not want us to post our code anywhere other than github but it is available here: https://github.com/IvanButBetter/MazeRunner/blob/main/Game(1).html